# Software design and cyclic Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have an issue in my application design. I have a item viewer application, let's call it `V` and want to extend it with an editor project, let's call it `E`.

`E` depends on many classes of `V`, because it provides a graphical preview of the items. So `E` there is a Maven dependency `E`->`V`. Now I want to integrate `E` into `V`, because users should be able to start the editor out of the viewer. That means I also have a Maven dependency `V`->`E` which causes a dependency cycle. I tried different `scope` values but was not able to break the cycle. How can I achieve this?

The `V` project is a very monolithic and not well-structured bunch of code and I don't want to divide it. In the `E` project I can do anything I want (in fact it already consists of many small projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split out the API parts of each project (basically the interfaces that are called from the other). This would give you dependencies like this:

```
v -> Vapi
E -> Vapi
V -> Eapi
E -> Eapi
```

and there are no cycles.

If you don't want to split V a scheme like this may work:

```
E -> V
E -> Eapi
V -> Eapi
```

Comment: I agree with that but it is difficult to split `V`. I updated the question.

Comment: I also tried that but when I when I build a Jar of `V` (with maven-shade-plugin), it does not contain the `E` libraries.

Comment: Why should it? It does not depend on E. To get a working system you need to build E. But if everything is too tightly coupled to make a clean split your only option is to put everything into one project.

Comment: I tried to add `E` as runtime dependency but run into a cycle again.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, V is only a module and can no longer be used stand alone. The full code is only contained in an E build.

Comment: Ok I think there is no way around modularizing `V`.

Comment: That is difficult. I would have to change many processes (CI, deployment) and some projects. `V` must stay the master project. It is a legacy, 5 year existing application.

Comment: Can't you solve that with some renaming of projects (V becomes Vlegacy and E becomes V). I don't know your environment, its just an idea.

Comment: No that is not an option. As I said, CI, deployment, scripts, SVN, and 5 developers depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your view code to work with an interface instead of a class; this is a best practice in any case. Put the relevant `interface` files in module `foo-api`, and then have `foo-domain` and `foo-view` depend on `foo-api`.